# Wordpress fatal memory error on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory, wordpress-4.6

I'm using wordpress 4.6, and when I try to activate a plugin, seo yaost, jetpack, for example, the error below.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /home/storage/2/2b/18/lgpconsulting/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php on line 206
```

I changed the following files:

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

wp-settings.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

.htacess

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all about memory issue

you need to increase

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M'); to define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

Also deactivate all the plugins and then try to activate plugins one by one

Comment: I increase it in wp-config.php file.

When I activate the Jetpack plugin, I can't more acess plugin session, because of memory error.

Comment: I've added define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'); to wp-config.php
And nothing changed.

Comment: @rod have you deactivate all the plugins ? then try to activate jetpack and all one by one

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

To see if there is errors.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to your webhost. You've made all the adjustments you can to raise the memory allocation, but the webhost's server settings are not allowing you to override their settings.